# A person working at a job for the longest period of time

Tags: word-request, idiomatic-language

How can I refer to a person who is working at a job for the longest period of time.

For example, imagine there are 10 people who work at the same office and one of them, let's say Amanda, has been working there for 10 years. The duration at which the other employers have worked at the office is less than 10 years.

What is the proper way to say that Amanda has been working more than the others at the office.

Is there any adjective I can use? For example can I use "oldest" in this sense? (However, this question is nothing to do with age for sure)

This example environment can be changed to a neigborhood,an apartment building, a society, an organization

Comment: Amanda has worked there *longer than* any of the other employees.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, the expression changes depending on the circumstance, in a job

> the most **senior** person

is often used to refer to the one there longest, but can also mean the highest in the heirarchy.

> **oldest**

often gets used, but can be confused with *chronological age*, usually additional context is provided.

> **oldest tenured** employee
>   **longest serving** employee
>   **oldest** resident in the apartment complex, first moved in...

Comment: We can also say this employee **has seniority** over the other employees, although this is usually in the context of who receives promotions or other benefits not based on merit.

Answer (score 0):

I read [this article](https://blog.coursera.org/eight-years-at-coursera-always-a-courserian/) yesterday and an expression solved the same question for myself, and in the article the author wrote that:

> Hi! I’m Currin Berdine, one of Coursera’s longest-tenured employees, and I’m thrilled to celebrate our 10th birthday with you.

I thought the "longest-tenured employee" would be one of the best fits.